# Is $Mvv^TM$ positive definite, if $M$ is symmetrical positive definite and $v$ is real valued vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, I've got symmetrical matrix $M$ which is positive definite and real valued vector $v$. And I'd like to know whether $Mvv^TM$ positive definite? If so, please explain why.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$x^TMvv^TMx = (v^TMx)^T(v^TMx) \geq 0$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However it is possible that
$$v^TMx = 0$$
for some $x \neq 0$. For example $v = (1,0)^T$, $M = I$ and $x = (0,1)^T$. Therefore the matrix
$$Mvv^TM$$ is only positive semidefinite.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the help!